# Debug Version of MFC app (runnable on another PC)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, mfc

Is it possible to static link mfc90d, msvcp90d and msvcrd to make it possible
to run a debug version of the program on a computer without installed Visual Studio?!
(At this point I can't make a release version)

Thank you in advance!

greets leon22

Answer (score 0):

You [can](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/6c090997-57a6-4b16-a998-22af447cb253#f4bfd9da-4407-4669-9847-5542c18ad201), but what about using the [remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t%28VS.71%29.aspx)? If QA or a client runs into something on just one machine/config, then that's a great way to catch something "in the act".

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you certainly can.** Static linking embeds all of the MFC code into your .EXE, eliminating the dependency on shared DLLs.

To do this in Visual Studio:

1. Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer, and click "Properties."
2. In the dialog that appears, select the "General" tab under the "Configuration Properties" header.
3. Set the "Use of MFC" property to **"Use MFC in a Static Library"**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I linked the MFC lib static I'm still get the error for missing msvcp90d and msvcrd!? I thought these libs are also included with "Use MFC in a Static Library"?!